# Transactional Replication: Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I have Transactional replication in one environment, I disable existing one and configuring it again, But While initialization in am getting following error

**Distributor Subsystem: Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.**

Same was working before with out any issues.

Can some onle help me on this?

Comment: What does your replication monitor say?

Comment: In Replication Monitor after all primary keys and Index are applied, that is at end of initialization  it shows this error message 'Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state' and starts to reinitialize again.

Comment: When I tried to see the commands using SP_Browsereplcmds with the trans_seqno it shows as SYNCSTAT.

Comment: In ran profiler for it  error is displayed after 'if object_id(N'sys.sp_MSrestoresavedforeignkeys','p')<0 Exec sys.sp_MSrestoresavedforeignkeys

if @@trancount > 0 rollback tram'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue on Replication, server restart resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved as of now. Just rebooting the server solved the problem.

Note: Raised EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION stack dumps